# Append content versus seeing it as a duplicate in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have XML tickets uploading to my ticket management software (Hesk). Every XML has a TRACKING ID, and previously if multiple XMLs have the same TRACKING ID, this script will simply process one XML, and let me know I have duplicates. I need the content of the XML to actually append when I upload, versus calling it a duplicate.

I have been trying for hours, but haven't been able to figure this one out.

```
    //Read the contents of XML tickets
    $this->xml_files = $this->loadDir("xml_tickets");
    //Make sure we got something
    if (!empty($this->xml_files)) {
        //Set response
        $this->response[] = "Registered " . count($this->xml_files) . " files";
        //Loop
        foreach ($this->xml_files as $current_file) {
            //Hmm
            $this->response[] = "Processing {$current_file}";
            //Contents
            $contents = file_get_contents("xml_tickets/{$current_file}");
            //Tickets
            $tickets = $this->extractor($contents, $current_file);
            //Make sure we got something
            if (!empty($tickets)) {
                $this->response[] = "{$current_file} Got " . count($tickets) . " ticket(s)";
                //Loop-de-loop
                foreach ($tickets as $currentTicket) {
                    if ($this->notDuplicate($currentTicket)) {

                        $currentTicket['html'] = $modsForHesk_settings['rich_text_for_tickets'];
                        
                        //Do the thing
                        $ticket = hesk_newTicket($currentTicket);
                        //Lel
                        if (!empty($ticket)) {
                            $this->response[] = "Created Ticket ({$ticket["trackid"]}) {$ticket["subject"]}";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->response[] = "Ticket is a duplicate";
                    }
```

Comment: Where/what should the content append to - is it a variable you have already?

Comment: These tickets upload to a MySQL table. Since it must use some logic in picking which of the file it considers writing to the table, versus considering it a duplicate, I was hoping for the script to say if the ‘trackingID’ are all the same, merge the content, versus dismissing the other XMLs as a duplicate. 

Hope that makes sense. Its a continuous feed, so every 10 mins a script runs to scan for new XMLs and it uploads them. The problem is if a ticket has already been created, it won’t ever update the status, because everything else associated with it is considered a duplicate.

Comment: Every XmL has the same tag which is <trackingID>. I was hoping I could use the tracking ID to correlate multiple XMLs

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hesk, but you're using a function to test if the ticket is a duplicate. Could you use that same functionality but return an existing ticket - then use a function to update that instead of creating a new one? e.g. you've got `hesk_newTicket` is there a similar `hesk_updateTicket`?

Comment: I do have a function called hesk_replies, which I believe would add a response to the ticket. I I tried, but i got an error  :  } else {
                        $this = hesk_replies;
                    }

Comment: Worst case scenario: if Hesk doesn't provide a function for updating a ticket, write your own function which updates the corresponding MySQL record if you find a dupe.